# Estate liability for co-signer to Sallie Mae student loan?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, estate-planning, death, co-sign

My son has student loans.  I co-signed on three that are currently with Sallie Mae. He stopped paying so I am doing that in order to protect my own credit.  What is my estate's liability should I die before the debt is discharged?  As a co-signer, does my obligation end with my death if my son is still around?

Answer (score 9):

Your estate would still be responsible for paying off the debt. That is your responsibility as a co-signer. Occasionally, people take out life insurance as part of the loan, which (depending on the terms) may kick in upon your death and pay off the loan.

If your son has stopped paying the loans, you may want to consider garnisheeing any wages he earns to reduce your exposure.

Comment: +1 life insurance  to hedge loans is a must in estate planning.

Comment: What happens if the estate is settled before the loan is declared delinquent and collection proceedings are started? If SallieMae does not assert her rights in probate court as a creditor, can she come back years later to sue the estate?

Comment: The estate cannot be settled before all outstanding loans are resolved.